# xamarin.ios app in xamarin form not building

Tags: xamarin

I am not able to build xamarin.ios project in xamarin form app. Getting error

> MessagingRemoteException: An error occured on client Build42164 while
>   executing a reply for topic
>   xvs/Build/4.2.1.64/execute-task/MyManager.iOS/188a903%2FACTool
>   DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path
>   "/Users/ascensive/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/MyManager.iOS/188a90393f778024e225bc6886195c37/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Contents.json.

Its searching Assets.xcassets folder, which is not found. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you already cleared bin and obj folder and clean & rebuild the solution? If no,  give it a try

Answer (score 0):

you have to right click on the Asset Catalogs > Add Asset Catalog. It will generate the Asset. Remember to turn on "Show All Files" in the Solution Explorer, sometimes it's created but you have to include in the project. By doing this, the contents.json is automatically created.